# 'Kernel does not include CapeMgr module' when am using beaglebone black with bonscript am getting the above error

Tags: node.js, beagleboneblack

'Kernel does not include CapeMgr module' when am using beaglebone black with 
   bonscript am getting the above error.. please check code here..

```
var b = require('bonescript');
var SerialPort = require('serialport').SerialPort;
//SerialPort = serialport.SerialPort;
var portName = '/dev/ttyO2';
var rs="";
 var options = {parity: 'even', parser: 
 b.serialParsers.readline("\n"),baudrate: 9600 };

 b.serialOpen(portName,options,onSerial);
 b.serialWrite(port,'1');
 function onSerial(x)
 {
    if(x.err){
    console.log('**Error**'+ JSON.stringify(x));
    rs= JSON.stringify(x.err);
  }
 if(x.event == 'open'){
    console.log('***OPENED***');
    rs='serial port open';
  }
 if(x.event == 'data'){
    console.log(String(x.data));
    rs=String(x.data);
  }
}
output:Kernel does not include Cape Mgr module
```